# How can I extract a users laptop/desktop model in php

Tags: php, model, sysinfo

Please i am seeking a way to get a users system information in php, mostly the name of the laptop/desktop maker e.g Lenovo/HP

I am aware of phpsysinfo, but it doesnt seem to have such info.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is mostly run server side, so I would not expect any such information which belongs to the client be available on the server.

phpsysinfo will only have the information of the system the code is executed on, most likely the server.

Comment: I don't know, but at least Javascript runs client side.